# c# drawing text using custom pixels

Tags: c#, fonts, pixel

I'm wondering if that's possible: 
I got a c# application with something like a display consisting of about 11000 circles drawn on the Form.

What I want to achieve is to be able to draw text on that display, but not using the "real" pixels, but using the circles (rectangles) drawn on the form as pixels.

**Edit 1:**

When drawing text in c#, you would i.e. use something like `Graphics.DrawString(...)`, giving the method a rectangle (so coordinates) in which the text should be drawn in. That text then is drawn in that rectangle using the screen pixels. What I want to do is draw text as well but not using the screen pixels but my custom pixels of which my display consists.

**Edit 2**

Method used to draw the circles on the Form; `Circles` is a list consisting of `Circle` objects, where `circleRectangle` returns the coordinates in which the circle should be drawn and `Filled` tells the method if the circle should be filled or not.

```
    public void DrawCircles(Graphics g)
    {

        graphics = g;
        graphics.SmoothingMode =System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, penthickness);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        for (int j = 0; j < Circles.Count;j++ )
        {
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, Circles[j].CircleRectangle);
            if (Circles[j].Filled)
                brush.Color = fillColor;
            else
                brush.Color = Color.White;
            graphics.FillEllipse(brush, Circles[j].CircleRectangle);

        }

    }
```

Is this possible and if yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Please can you clarify what exactly you mean? P.S. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write on an invisible BitMap with the DrawText method and then scan the bitmap's pixels and turn the corresponding circles on.

Did that last week with the cells of  DataGridView. Real easy.

Here is some code:

```
    public void drawText(string text, Font drawFont)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(paintColor);
        Point point = new Point( yourOriginX, yourOriginY );

        G.DrawString(text, drawFont, brush, point);

        for (int x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y++)
            {
                Color pix = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    setCell(x, y, pix);     //< -- set your custom pixels here!
            }
        bmp.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
        G.Dispose();
    }
```

**Edit**: You would use your dimensions and your origin for the DrawString, of course

Comment: thank you very much - seems like this is what I'm looking for; I'll try that out and accept the answer as soon as possible!

Comment: Sure, good luck. Two things I noticed: - The unset pixels will have an Aplha channel value of 0.  - And the magnification shows antialiasing pixels halo the letters in all colors. If you have questions, ask!