# forming letters out of binary arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to create a function that would receive an alphanumeric letter as parametter and return a NxM sized binary array, in which 1's and 0's would form the letter given.

For example, for letter A and B, the arrays could look like this:

```
00000110000    11111111100
00001001000    11000000011
00011001100    11000000011
00111111100    11111111110
01100000110    11000000011
11000000011    11000000011
11000000011    11000000011
11000000011    11111111111
```

*tip: if you strech your eyes you can see the letters a bit better*

The only way I know how to do this is by manually creating arrays for each character and insert them into switch-case. Which seems extremely dull and unprofessional.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: +1, the question is clearly stated, and he's asking for ideas, not for "write my code for me".

Comment: Render chars into Image (best would be mono spaced font). Than check pixel color (black = 1, white = 0). 
If you want to display more than a single char, render the whole text into an image and seperate it accordingly.

Comment: @Heinzi, this doesnt appear to be a question that can be answered then, only discussed. -1

Comment: @paqogomez: CSharpie's suggestion (rendering characters of a monospaced font to a bitmap and converting the bitmap to an array) sounds like a suitable answer to me. In general, I do think that "Is there a more elegant way to do X?" questions are on-topic here. (Have a look at those "Can I do X with LINQ?" questions, if you need upvoted examples.)

Comment: @paqogomez every question can be answered. I really need a sugestion on how to implement this, and I don't see why SO would be against this. If you have any sugestion on how to make my question more clear, be my guest.

Comment: AlexandruSeverin, I mean no disrespect.  @Heinzi and I have differing opinions on if a question this broad can be answered well enough to be effective.  For my part, I prefer to see a bit more code.  I do like CSharpie's take on the problem however.  I think its about as specific as you can be given the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881312/c-sharp-drawing-text-using-custom-pixels/22881391#22881391).

The OP there wanted to draw circles as his 'custom pixels'.

The idea is to draw the Characters you want in the size and font you like onto an (invisible) bitmap and then read the set pixels from it and write them in your 'custom pixels', i.e. your digits.

It may sound a bit daunting, but if you look at the code provided you'll see that it really is rather straightforward and it works quite well!

Answer (score 1):

Here, the OCR Algorithms (Optical Character Recognition) are very useful.

You can create as already was suggested a bunch of pixels and than use this kind of algs.

In case you need something that already exists : http://digit.lk/optical-character-recognitionocr-in-c/ or try this one : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476142/Optical-Character-Recognition