# Viewing Monochrome Bitmap in TextBox

Tags: c#, bitmap, binary, monochrome

Forgive me if it has been addressed, but I was unable to find it anywhere. I've been trying to get a monochrome bitmap to become visible in a text box. When I open a black and white bitmap image I would like to be able to see the form of the image made up of 1 and 0 (1 black, 0 white). I figured if I converted the below int(i) toString that the binary would show up, but I guess it's not that easy. Does anyone have any experience with this? Hopefully there is a simple way to perform this kind of function.

```
for (int i = 0x7F; i < 0xFF; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = Convert.ToString(i, 2); }
// 0x7F = 127, 0xFF = 255
```

**Here is a photo of Micky Mouse:**

[image]

**Here is how Micky looks in binary:**
[image]

**I was hoping to see something like this occur:**

[image]

In my code I have decimals 1-126 being processed as actual characters, but I have 127-255 being converted to binary.

Currently I am using a drag/drop functionality and would like to preserve this is possible. Here is my current class for this drag drop RichTextBox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PCL_Utility
{
    public class DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        public DragDropRichTextBox()
        {
            this.AllowDrop = true;
            this.DragDrop += DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop;
        }

        public static class BinaryFile
        {

            private static string[] __byteLookup = new string[256];


            static BinaryFile()
            {
                // Display printable ASCII characters as-is
                for (int i = 0x00; i < 0x7F; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = ((char)i).ToString(); }

                // Display non-printable ASCII characters as \{byte value}
                for (int i = 0; i <= 0x00; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = "\\" + i.ToString(); }

                for (int i = 0x7F; i < 0xFF; i++) { __byteLookup[i] = Convert.ToString(i, 2); }

                __byteLookup[0] = ""; // NULL 

            }

            public static string ReadString(string filename)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

                return String.Join("", (from i in fileBytes select __byteLookup[i]).ToArray());
            }
        }

        void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            //string[] fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
            string[] fileText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

            if (fileText != null)
            {
                foreach (string name in fileText)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString (name) + "\n -------- End of File -------- \n\n");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm mostly a beginner, so whatever answer comes my way I will do my best to understand. But I may have some questions.

Comment: Your "one's and zero's" example looks like [ascii art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), which is not the same as the binary for an image.

Comment: Kevin. I think this is perfect. This must not be in binary, but is in fact ASCII art. I've been racking my brain on this. I probably just need to the the 95 printable ASCII characters and leave the non printable ascii characters blank. It's a start!

Comment: You should answer officially, and I will give you the green check if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that was the answer. I do think this is binary after doing some research about "bit"mapped images. I think it's just a matter of making sure the right characters are in there. Not sure. I did notice that the bitmaps in the file I am using are all above the 128th bit.

Comment: Ascii art is all in printable characters. What I am doing uses non-printable characters.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, except I already have the bitmap in binary, I just don't know why it doesn't line up. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hscream/ImagetoBinary02132007164649PM/ImagetoBinary.aspx

Comment: This sounds like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002049/forming-letters-out-of-binary-arrays/24002499#24002499) in reverse..

Answer (score 0):

The following method should give you a string array of zero's and one's, representing the specified image:

```
private static string ConvertToString(Bitmap image)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder imageLine = new StringBuilder();

    // Iterate each pixel from top to bottom
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        // Iterate each pixel from left to right
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            Color pixelColour = image.GetPixel(x, y);

            // Determine how "dark" the pixel via the Blue, Green, and Red values
            // (0x00 = dark, 0xFF = light)
            if (pixelColour.B <= 0xC8
                && pixelColour.G <= 0xC8
                && pixelColour.R <= 0xC8)
            {
                imageLine.Append("1");  // Dark pixel
            }
            else
            {
                imageLine.Append("0");  // Light pixel
            }
        }

        // Add line of zero's and one's to end results
        result.AppendLine(imageLine.ToString());
        imageLine.Clear();
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

This is based on [the link you provided](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hscream/ImagetoBinary02132007164649PM/ImagetoBinary.aspx), but I've amended the code in a few places, like how the comparison of the pixel values was previously also based on the Alpha, and the string representations of the values.

The following console application code should output the result, but I wouldn't recommend it for large images; maybe output to a text file instead?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read image into memory
            var img = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\MickyMouse.png");

            // Modify width of console buffer to keep each line of characters "on one line"
            Console.SetBufferSize(img.Width + 10, img.Height + 10);

            Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(img));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string ConvertToString(Bitmap image)
        {
            // Code from above
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` to the project in order for it to compile.

Comment: Note I choose an arbitrary value of `0xC8 (200)` so that the code wasn't only considering black pixels as a 1, and all other shades of grey to white as 0.  It worked for the provided image in the question, but may need tweaking for other images.

Comment: I'm a very new programmer. This is the second thing I've written and the most complex. I'll keep working with this. Thanks for your help.  I actually only need black and white. Also, just a side thought. The file format I will be importing is a text file that contains a bitmap image in the middle, then more text below that. I'm hoping to make the bitmap and text both visible. My code above currently allows my text to show up properly, but the bitmap is a nasty mess. I'll edit so you can see what I mean.