# Draw splines with a list of points in a 2D Array

Tags: c#, algorithm, bezier, spline, nurbs

I've looked into **splines**, **nurbs** and **Bezier curves** bit I can't find an algorithm that fits my needs. I would appreciate help with an algorithm or function that can draw a curve based on points in a 2D array.

**Example:**

First starting point in my array : ex arr[1,2] = new Point(1,2)

> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

**Output:**

> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,**1**,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,**1**,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,**1**,0,0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,**1**,**1**,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,**0**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You can scan the array to find points ('1's) but this doesn't make sure which to connect. Nor do we know what exactly you want as a result? Pixels? Points plus control points? Very unclear. In GDI+ there are nice function to draw bezie curves from points.. But you need both the points and in the right __order__!

Comment: I want the result to be like the second array. i've n points in my array then i want to change every 0 by 1 where my spline go through, like Bresenham's algorithm but for curves.

Comment: So the points should be connected left-to-right, like the graph of a continuous function?

Comment: Either do the math or cheat. To cheat you can draw onto a small bitmap and the read out the pixels and put the 1s into the 2nd array. I did something similar [with characters here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881312/c-sharp-drawing-text-using-custom-pixels/22881391?s=269|0.0000#22881391)

Comment: i could "cheat" but i really want this algorithm because i'll need it a lot and it would be easier than reading a 1200*800 bitmap n times. But thanks for helping me.

Comment: Good luck then. Remeber you still need to determine the order of the points.. ! - (And with the size you really could use the cheat with lockbits and might even be faster than some self-written  algorithm; the system usually is optimized best.. ;-)

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bresenham+curve

Comment: Thanks @m69, i'll continue my research.

Comment: So you want rasterization of curve. Bezier could be rasterized with subdivision method. Perhaps you don't need advanced methods like http://antigrain.com/index.html

Comment: What is wrong with BEZIER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of this question: defining a smooth curve that goes through those points, and then drawing that curve into your array.

A common curve type that goes through several defined points is the [Catmull-Rom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline).  You might want to see if this meets your needs.

To define your Catmull-Rom spline, you'd want to scan your 2D array from left to right, and wherever there is a 1, add a point to the spline.  You'll also need to come up with a curve parameterization.  Using the column number as the parameter value for each point would probably give good results.

In terms of drawing, there are a few different approaches.  Catmull-Rom splines are parametric, so you could try computing the point on the curve at a lot of t values, and setting the corresponding array location.  If you have a line-drawing primitive implemented (like Bresenham line drawing), you can compute fewer points on the spline and  fill in with lines.  There are also other methods, like decomposing splines into beziers or scanline methods, but they're more complicated and probably unnecessary.